# cocos2d: How do I Control a scrolling map

Tags: iphone, scroll, cocos2d-iphone, tiles, parallax

I made my map to scroll automatically however I would like to know how can I slow down the scrolling before the map reaches the end and when it does I would like the map to stop scrolling. I want to know how to do this because my game is about the player trying to shoot the enemy before he reaches the end of the map where there is shelter for him to hide. I would like that before the enemy reaches the shelter have the scrolling slow down and when the enemy reaches the shelter I would like the map to stop scrolling.
Here is the code:

```
@implementation GameplayScrollingLayer

// Scrolling with TileMap Layers inside of a Parallax Node
-(void)addScrollingBackgroundWithTileMapInsideParallax {
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CGSize levelSize = [[GameManager sharedGameManager] 
                    getDimensionsOfCurrentScene];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    tileMapNode = [CCTMXTiledMap 
                   tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"Level2TileMap.tmx"];
} else {
    tileMapNode = [CCTMXTiledMap 
                   tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"Level2TileMapiPhone.tmx"];
}



CCTMXLayer *groundLayer = [tileMapNode layerNamed:@"GroundLayer"];
CCTMXLayer *rockColumnsLayer = [tileMapNode 
                                layerNamed:@"RockColumnsLayer"];
CCTMXLayer *rockBoulderLayer = [tileMapNode 
                                layerNamed:@"RockBoulderLayer"];


parallaxNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
[parallaxNode setPosition:
 ccp(levelSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2)];
float xOffset = 0.0f;


xOffset = (levelSize.width/2);
[groundLayer retain];
[groundLayer removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
[groundLayer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
[parallaxNode addChild:groundLayer z:30 parallaxRatio:ccp(1,1) 
        positionOffset:ccp(0,0)];
[groundLayer release];


xOffset = (levelSize.width/2) * 0.8f;
[rockColumnsLayer retain];
[rockColumnsLayer removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
[rockColumnsLayer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
[parallaxNode addChild:rockColumnsLayer z:20 
         parallaxRatio:ccp(0.2,1) 
        positionOffset:ccp(xOffset, 0.0f)]; 
[rockColumnsLayer release];


xOffset = (levelSize.width/2) * 0.3f;
[rockBoulderLayer retain];
[rockBoulderLayer removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
[rockBoulderLayer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f)];
[parallaxNode addChild:rockBoulderLayer z:30 
         parallaxRatio:ccp(0.7,1) 
        positionOffset:ccp(xOffset, 0.0f)];
[rockBoulderLayer release];


[self addChild:parallaxNode z:1];
}

// Accelerometer
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration        *)acceleration { //new
shipSpeedY = 9.0 + acceleration.x*20;
shipSpeedX = -acceleration.y*20;
}

// Updating ship based on accelerometer
-(void)updateShip { 
float maxY = winSize.height - ship.contentSize.height/2;
float minY = ship.contentSize.height/2;
float newY = ship.position.y + shipSpeedY;
newY = MIN(MAX(newY, minY), maxY);

float maxX = winSize.width - ship.contentSize.width/2;
float minX = ship.contentSize.width/2;
float newX = ship.position.x + shipSpeedX;
newX = MIN(MAX(newX, minX), maxX);

ship.position = ccp(newX, newY);
}

// Making background scroll automatically 
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt { 
[self updateShip];

CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(-100, 0);
parallaxNode.position = ccpAdd(parallaxNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));


}

// Adding sprite ship
-(id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
   winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    ship=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ship.png"];
    ship.position=ccp(60,160);
    [self addChild:ship z:100];

    self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES; //new
    [self scheduleUpdate]; //new

    [self addScrollingBackgroundWithTileMapInsideParallax];
}
return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```